# Single Purpose Educational Android Tablet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, kiosk-mode

This question is not very technical but I had to ask it somewhere, and this was a promising place to get answers. Please help.
I have to provide Educational-Tablets to High-School Students. We want to make sure that those tablets are not misused and only 2 application (developed by us) run on the tablet. I went through many MDM (Mobile Device Management) solutions but none seemed promising. Is there any way (Any Android Native Functionality) to ensure the "Single Purpose Use" of the Tablet?

Comment: You would need some sort of app locker that runs as a device administrator ... You would only need to run as an administrator to stop it from being uninstalled without a password ! ..   Their are a few open source app lockers that you could use, but their not very secure when it comes to uninstalling them !..... An easier alternative would be to build a simple launcher that only has your two apps in it ! .. And use another application to lock settings, Locking settings is the only way to stop uninstalling apps

Comment: Modern Android versions support "Guest Mode". Use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good business and educational solutions out there which are either free or at very low cost to achieve this. My company makes one, and you can find out more on [our website](https://www.relution.io) -> look for Android Kiosk Mode. If you have any questions, please do not hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native functionality to lock down tablets, There's Screen pinning on Android devices (5.0 and above) which lets you lock down the device to an app screen, but this feature has its limitations, users can unpin it and access other apps and content on the device just as easy. That’s why we made it a point to offer a powerful [Kiosk mode](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mdm-kiosk-mode/) on our MDM solution. We have whole school districts with tablets deployed in Kiosk mode with [Hexnode MDM](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/). You can lock down the devices to single app or a set of applications of your choice. You can choose to have an app auto-launch in fixed time intervals, selectively enable various settings toggles, seamlessly update Kiosk apps and more. I'm pretty sure you'll fall in love.